# Skip Serializing properties generically during Web API processing

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

During WebAPI Response processing, we need to log the response/request body and headers with the security properties being skipped. With Newtonsoft Json, Since the actual response should contain the properties, "Ignore" attribute cannot be placed. We have implemented general filter to handle all Web API Methods that takes excluded property key names as list. Following are approaches tried.

1. Doing Jobject.Parse and traversing through JTokens and excluding.
2. Using JsonTextReader and applying conditions while reading.

Both are taking milli seconds time which was not acceptable because its just for logging.

Is there any Optimal way to acheive this?

Comment: Can you give a [simple but complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are doing currently?

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class without the security property, use the base class for logging the data and the child one to have everything.

Or create an interface from your class and create a new class with Ignore attribute which you use to log the result.

Comment: The scenario is before sending response back, we have to capture and log. While logging, some properties should be skipped.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. In the first case, if you log a child instance as a base class, you won't log the properties of the child one. Then you return the answer as a child class which contains all the properties.